# Как парсить динамический сайт?

Tags: php, javascript, парсер, casperjs

Как парсить контент с SPA приложений? Пробовал casperjs, но что-то не получается.
Есть у кого дельные советы или гайды? Спасибо

Comment: а какой источник вы хотите парсит?

Comment: Отслеживайте в "инструментах разработчика" XHR-запросы и ответы и анализируйте их.

Comment: Ну вообще как бы парсить контент не проблема, проблема получить этот контент. Так как SPA рендерится не на сервере а в браузере. Поэтому формулировка вопроса не совсем точная.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov вижу нужную мне информацию в XHR, а как получить доступ из php или js-а к этой информации? чтобы не самому смотреть, а программно. спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если сайт является SPA, то все данные он получает через своё же api. Следовательно, парсить вообще ничего не надо, надо просто слать к его api такие же запросы, какие он шлёт сам. Ну а уж json распарсить, надеюсь, проблем нет.

Comment: А можно вопрос по терминологии? Если через это api он будет получать не json, а куски html-кода (возможно, завёрнутые в json, чтоб страшнее было) — это уже нельзя называть SPA?

Comment: @andreymal, можно. Но это во-первых странно, а во-вторых, не влияет на ответ - надо парсить ответы api.

Comment: А если доступа к API нету? И я могу взаимодействовать с сайтом только как пользователь? Спарсить данные не беда, проблема в том чтобы парсер "дождался" генерации всего контента на сайте.

Comment: @J.Doe, ну как у сайта доступ к api есть, а у тебя нет???

Comment: @Qwertiy повторил запрос постмэном - получил корректный ответ. Чувствую себя немного глупо. Даже не знал что так можно. Большое спасибо за помощь.